# Divide timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question regarding time in MySQL.
How do i get a time stamp like this:

```
2014-12-07 12:54:42.000000
```

To correctly insert itself in this table:
The timestamp has to divide to,Hour,Dayname,Weeknumber,Daynumber
I need a fixed value of 1 in every layar of the table

```
+-------------+----------+--------+-----+-----+-----------x
| fixedval    | Hour     | Dayname| Weeknumber| Daynumber |          
+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1           |          |        |           |           | 
| 1           |          |        |           |           |                
| 1           |          |        |           |           |                
| 1           |          |        |           |           |                
| 1           |          |        |           |           |                
+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: With that timestamp, what's the expected table data?

Comment: Do not store timestamps in this format

Comment: Why do you want to store timestamp to save like that?

Comment: @Cloud It is because i can then easily see patterns in my data.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions for that

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
Insert into table
(fixedval,hour,dayname,weeknumber,daynumber)
(Select 1, hour(inputdate), dayname(inputdate), weekofyear(inputdate), dayofyear(inputdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT HOUR(your_date) as Hour,DAYNAME(your_date) as Dayname,WEEK(your_date) as Weeknumber, DAYOFMONTH(your_date) as datenumber from table.
```

**NOTE**: You can use either DAYOFMONTH/DAYOFWEEK for day number.